# Unix Shell Script get all specific string on a file and modify it vertically

Tags: shell, unix

I have a TEXT file contains strings

example `logs.txt`:

```
value1 A
value2 B
value3 c
row
row
row
value1 A
value2 D
value3 c
row
value1 E
value2 B
value3 A
row
row
value1 Z
value2 B
value3 E
```

All I want is to get all value A, value B, value C vertically with "|" pipe delimiter

Output:

```
value1 A|value2 B|value3 C
value1 A|value2 D|value3 C
value1 E|value2 B|value3 A
value1 Z|value2 B|value3 E
```

Comment: You could probably do this with the mother of all awk scripts but it really is demanding something more than a shell script. Please give some better example data.  What significance does "row" have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What is the pattern that should be used to detect the 'value' lines? Is it 'value'?  What happens if there is a 'value D' line as well? Can you end up with 'row' lines in between 'value' lines? What should happen if there are only two 'value' lines? Is it necessary to case-convert 'c' as found in the input to 'C' as found in the output?  Is it 'output a new line every three value lines'?

Comment: Hi Jonahtan, yes it posible to have "value D" but keyword was "value" and the my scenario has alway 3 keyword "value" in sequenced

Answer (score 0):

Making some possibly unrealistic assumptions, this can be managed with:

```
sed -e '/^value /!d' -e '/value/{N;N;s/\n/|/g;}' data
```

Primary assumption:

1. When you get a 'value' line, it is followed by two more 'value' lines (there are no 'row' lines in the middle of a set of three 'value' lines).
2. There's no need to case convert `value c` in the input to `value C` in the output.
3. It doesn't matter what appears after the 'value' and the space (so any letters or words — indeed, any text at all — is OK after the 'value').

Strictly, the `/value/` in the second `-e` argument is not necessary, but it emphasizes that it only processes the 'value' lines.

---

To make this into a script, use:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e '/^value /!d' -e '/value/{N;N;s/\n/|/g;}' "$@"
```

The `"$@"` means 'all the arguments passed to the script', and is expected to be a set of file names to be processed (there's nothing to stop an inventive user passing more `sed` commands if they so choose — though it likely won't do them much good if they try).  The output goes to standard output, so you can capture it with I/O redirection or piping.

Optionally prefix the `sed` with `exec`, as in:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sed -e '/^value /!d' -e '/value/{N;N;s/\n/|/g;}' "$@"
```

You won't be able to measure the performance benefit that's there very easily (it is tiny).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, yes there will no row lines in the middle of a set of three "value" lines

Comment: how can i use this code "sed -e '/^value /!d' -e '/value/{N;N;s/\n/|/g;}' data"

Comment: #! /bin/bash sed -e '/^value /!d' -e '/value/{N;N;s/\n/|/g;}' data (SOMETHING LIKE THIS?)

Comment: please give me more idea on how to solve this scenario. i wan to make a ".sh" file that will run on "PuTTy"

Comment: and please refer to the changes of the example... thanks you very much

Comment: Occasionally, people have to sleep :)